# In Python for parameter typing, do you use the capital versions of dict and list?

Tags: python

Apologies, am new to Python so a very basic question. Below is an example line of my method definition. Where would I be using capital Dict/List and lowercase Dict/List?

Thanks in advance!

Example scenarios below

```
def execute_signals(self, parameter1: dict[list], parameter2: dict) -> list[dict]:

def execute_signals(self, parameter1: Dict[List], parameter2: Dict) -> List[Dict]:

def execute_signals(self, parameter1: dict[List], parameter2: dict) -> List[dict]:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Python 3.8 and earlier, the name of the collection type is capitalized, and the type is imported from the `typing` module.

Python 3.5 - 3.8 (*also works in Python 3.9+*):

```py
from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple
x: List[int] = [1]
x: Set[int] = {6, 7}
x: Dict[str, float] = {"field": 2.0}
x: Tuple[int, str, float] = (3, "yes", 7.5)
x: Tuple[int, ...] = (1, 2, 3)
```

Python 3.9+:

```py
x: list[int] = [1]
x: set[int] = {6, 7}
x: dict[str, float] = {"field": 2.0}
x: tuple[int, str, float] = (3, "yes", 7.5)
x: tuple[int, ...] = (1, 2, 3)
```

I recommend you read through the [mypy's docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html) about type hints.

Answer (score 6):

The `List` or `Dict` have to be imported from the `typing` module.
Before python 3.9 it was necessary, cause built-in `list` wouldn't allow you to do something like this:

```py
list[int]
```

It would be a syntax error. It was introduced in **Python 3.9**, so if you are using that (or newer version) you can use lowercase.

It's also worth to take a look at this: https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/

Starting with **Python 3.7**, when `from __future__ import annotations` is used, function and variable annotations can parameterize standard collections directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the capital versions of `Dict` and `List` refer to the abstract base classes for dictionaries and lists, respectively. These classes are part of the `collections.abc` module and are used primarily for type checking and duck typing.

However, in function annotations or parameter typing, it's more common to use the lowercase versions of `dict` and `list`, as they refer to the concrete classes. For example:

```
def my_function(my_list: list, my_dict: dict) -> int:
    # function body here
```

This function takes a list and a dictionary as arguments, and returns an integer. Note that we are using the lowercase versions of `list` and `dict` for parameter typing.

Comment: "In Python, the capital versions of Dict and List refer to the abstract base classes for dictionaries and lists, respectively"  this is incorrect, there are no `Dict` or `List` [in `collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) ... these come from `typing` module instead